# MySQL table fields comments instead of names in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

On web forms in application created with CakePHP, instead of column names as labels (next to input text fields), I need to display field comments.

Can you tell me which will be best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try anything? Can you add some code? In its current format, this question is too vague to be answered. Please read the [faq] to learn what kind of questions should be asked here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
echo $this->Form->input('field', array(
    'before' => 'Description of the field',
    'label' => false
));
```

and it will output:

```
<div class="input">
Description of the field
<input name="data[Model][field]" type="text" value="" id="ModelField" />
</div>
```